# Filter ripples and their effect on signal quality

Tags: digital-communications

Ripples cause an amplitude distortion in addition to a phase distortion expressed in terms of RMS phase deviation (from linear) or group delay variation over a certain signal bandwidth.
The question is are they related? , i.e. can one calculate the RMS phase deviation (or group delay variation) knowing the ripple amplitude variation (expressed say in terms of peak to peak)

Comment: The existence of constant group delay filters with amplitude ripple (i.e. just about any FIR filter) should tell you : no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can one calculate the RMS phase deviation (or group delay variation) knowing the ripple amplitude variation (expressed say in terms of peak to peak)

Generally not. There are many different systems that have the same amplitude response but different phase responses. If you know that your system is minimum phase, you can actually calculate the phase response from the amplitude response (using the Hilbert Transform) so this may help.

The amplitude variation alone is rarely helpful since they are many systems that have the same variation but very different absolute responses.

Comment: Doesn't amplitude variation express the fact that incident and reflected waves at different frequencies  add sometimes more constructively and sometimes more destructively depending on the phase?

Comment: (Cont.) In that case and suppose the amplitude variation is approximated as a sine wave, can't we derive an approximate formula that relates the amplitude deviation to the phase deviation?

Comment: No. Look at the simple case of an all pass filter. It has plenty of phase variation but no amplitude variation at all. A linear phase filter is the opposite: plenty of amplitude variation but constant group delay. Unless you have some additional knowledge the amplitude ripple doesn't tell you anything about group delay or phase ripple

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you can use the Hilbert transform to get between phase and amplitude response for certain simple types of filter known as minimum phase filters. In general, this means a single path through the filter, so no summing of two parallel branches (like you get in group delay correctors!)

This works in practice when you are doing filter theory, and have the mathematical representation of the filter algebraically, or in double precision arithmetic.

This does not work at all well in practice if you are measuring a real filter of any non-trivial order. Measurement errors and noise, and component losses, create so much perturbation that the transformed response is worthless, except for the very lowest order filters.